# Add a new column based on string value from an existing column in Rstudio

Tags: r, string, dplyr, multiple-columns

I have a data set in R containing multiple columns. One column `room_type` contains either the string values `Entire home/apt` or `Shared room` or `Private room` or it's blank. I want to create a new column `room_type_new` where string values are based on the column `room_type`. Note: There are over 100 000 rows in the data set.

See below:

```
room_type          room_type_new
Entire home/apt    Entire home
Private room       Shared home
Shared room        Shared home
NA                 NULL
```

I tried this code, which prints the correct output but doesn't pass the new values to `room_type_new`:

```
data1$room_type <- as.character(data1$room_type)
data1$room_type_new <- NA
data1$room_type_new <- as.character(data1$room_type_new)

    data1%>%
      mutate(room_type_new = case_when(.$room_type %in% c("Entire home/apt") ~ "Entire home",.$room_type %in% c("Private room", "Shared room") ~ "Shared home")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(room_type_new = case_when(str_detect(room_type, "Entire") ~ 
     'Entire home', is.na(room_type) ~ NA_character_, TRUE ~ "Shared home"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, it still doesn't pass the new values (ie Entire home or Shared home or NULL) to the new column room_type_new. It is still NA. But it prints the first 20 rows and the output is correct. So what's missing is to pass it on to room_type_new. Can't seem to figure it out :(

Comment: @FeliciaNathhorstMalmgren  You can't have `NULL` on a vector  It can be in a `list` though

Comment: @FeliciaNathhorstMalmgren its because you have not saved the result. just do `df2 <-df1%>%....` continue with the code. Then check the results of `df2`

Answer (score 0):

Build df:

```
df <- data.frame(room_type = as.character(c("Entire home/apt", "Private room", "Shared room")), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Base R one liner assuming only two unique values for df$room_type_new:

```
df$room_type_new <- ifelse(grepl("Entire home/apt", df$room_type), "Entire home", "Shared home")
```

Base R one liner if > 2 unique values for df$room_type_new, nest the ifelse:

```
df$room_type_new <- ifelse(grepl("Entire home/apt", df$room_type), "Entire home", ifelse(grepl("Private room|Shared room", df$room_type), "Shared home", "")
```

Also the reason why your output is being passed to anything is because your not assigning the result to an object -- using your code:

```
data1 <- 
 data1%>%
  mutate(room_type_new = case_when(.$room_type %in% c("Entire home/apt") ~ "Entire home",.$room_type %in% c("Private room", "Shared room") ~ "Shared home")
```

Comment: No worries, enjoy learning R, it is a truly beautiful language but takes some time. Also please upvote my answer if you found it useful !

Comment: I did but since I just created my profile it doesn't show (but is recorded) :)